# when talkback opened, app does not react to long press

Tags: android, talkback

I am developing an app with SAMSUNG GT-I8580. There is a ListView that can react to long press event when the talkback is disabled. However, the app does not react to long press action after I enabled the talkback function. It seems that talkback has overides the long press event, I am not sure. How can I solve this problem? Thanks for help!

Answer (score 5):

There are two ways to do it:

1) Double tap but on the second tap, hold.

2) Use two fingers to tap once and hold. Unfortunately, this is difficult if (like me) you have large fingers, or the area is small.